# Why is it useful to have only $2$ orientations for 3D oriented volumes and not $3!$? (And why not $n!$ for $n$D?)

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, intuition, exterior-algebra, orientation

Say we have three (non-coplanar) vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Geometrically they can be used to define $3$ distinct edges of a unique *non-oriented* 3D parallelipiped. We define two distinct *oriented* 3D parallelipipeds corresponding to this non-oriented one. One oriented parallelelipiped corresponds to even permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ and the other to odd permutations.

> **Question:** Geometrically, why is it meaningful/useful to define a notion of oriented parallelipiped that is identified with $3!/2$ distinct permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$? Why not one distinct "oriented" object for each of the $3!$ distinct permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$?

This corresponds to how the determinant of the even permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ (when treated as columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix) has the opposite sign of the odd permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$. So an answer to the question would imply one explantion for why the determinant should be considered "most useful", rather than say some function of the three vectors which gave distinct values differing by factors of e.g. the $(3!)$th = $6$th roots of unity for each of the $3!$ distinct permutations of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$.

Please let me know if there is anything I should clarify, or whether you believe this question to be a duplicate or there to be some similar issue.

**Note:** This question actually generalizes to oriented $n$-dimensional volumes for arbitrary $n$ (replace $3!$ with $n!$), and conceptually my question is about the geometric interpretation of skew-symmetric algebras generally. Discussing only the determinant in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is to make the question as accessible to as many people as possible.

Comment: I think the formula would be $\frac{n!}{n}$ because there are $n!$ ways to order the vectors and then we must divide by $n$ because rotations are indistinguishable.

Comment: I think the first question is 'if not the derivative, then what?'. The derivative is invariant under rotations of the space and any function that distinguishes between specific directions would not be. The idea that the coordinate system is not sacrosanct and that entities should be 'coordinate-free' is a fundamental concept of linear algebra/geometry.

Comment: Note that the determinant isn't even specifically necessary for this; if we want to talk about the space of _invertible_ $3\times 3$ matrices as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^9$ then we soon discover that this space has two connected components: one corresponding to positive derivatives and one corresponding to negative.

Comment: @AlanAbraham To confirm I understand what you're saying, "orientation" should be a rotation invariant property, so permutations of the vectors that could be transformed into each other by rotation should be defined to correspond to the same oriented (hyper)volume?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It sounds like your idea is similar to Alan Abraham's. I know that the "total derivative" is a linear transformation, but it seems more complicated than necessary in this context. Basically I want to understand how you would explain to a middle schooler who knows 0 calculus or linear algebra, but understands basic coordinate geometry, why it makes sense to have only two values for the determinant, or what is a "3-dimensional orientation" and why there are only 2 orientations in 3D and not 3 or 6 or whatever.